# Why a canvas update reload the page ? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I would like to implement a signature system inside my form, I use "react-signature-canvas" for this.
Unfortunately, when I try to use it some problem appears.

My main problem is the reloading my page. Usually in React When you update something ,just the render changing without reloading. But here it does ... Is it linked to the canvas system ? I don't want the reload of my page... It's so ugly for a PWA.
For example when I click on "clear" or "trim" the page reload.

This is my code: I removed some parts of it to be clearer

```js
const Consultation4 = () => {
    const sigPad = {}
    const [trimmedDataUrl,setTrimmedDataUrl] =  useState(null);

    const clear = () => sigPad.clear();
    const trim = () => {
        setTrimmedDataUrl(sigPad.getTrimmedCanvas().toDataURL('image/png'));
    }
 ...
(In the render)
    <FormGroup tag="fieldset" className="form-group">
       <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
             <div className="col-4 margin-left--12px">
                 <legend>Please sign here:</legend>
             </div>
             <div className="col-4 margin-button-clear">
                <button onClick={clear} className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Clear</button>
             </div>
             <div className="col-4 margin-button-clear">
                <button onClick={trim} className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Trim</button>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>

       <div className='border_grey'>
          <SignaturePad ref={sigPad} />
       </div>
   </FormGroup>
   {trimmedDataUrl ? <img src={trimmedDataUrl}/> : null}
}
```

Could you help me please ? Thanks in advance

PS: I have a second little problem, when I try to use `sigPad.isEmpty()` the compilator said "*this method does not exist*". But it exist in the doc of signature-pad-canvas (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-signature-canvas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default type of button elements is`submit`. Try button tags like

```
<button type="button" ....
```

within the form to stop submission from them.  Text input elements may also need attention to stop pressing `enter` from submitting the form as well.